Derive magnetic space group from lattice space group
Consider we have a simple cubic lattice, space group P23. At each corner of the cubic lattice there is one atom.
Now, if we assign a spin to each atom, and let the spins align in a ferromagnetic fashion. What is the magnetic space group of this system now?
A more general question: For a given space group, plus a particular spin arrangement, is there a standard way to derive its magnetic space group?

